# Laravel Eloquent get json from nested mysql data

Tags: php, nested, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have tabel like this

```
id  name         parent_id     order_id
1   software       0             1
2   hardware       0             2
3   windows        1             3
4   linux          1             4
5   mouse          2             5
6   keyword        2             6
```

And I use Laravel 5.1 Eloquent
How to get data in model like this

```
[{"id":1,"children":[{"id":3},{"id":4}]},{"id":2,"children":[{"id":5},{"id":6}]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a best way to do this.

The package [etrepat/baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum) is so awesome and easy. It has everything you need about nesting elements. Just add it to your composer dependencies and enjoy.

You can also add these methods to your Model and use them as relations.

```
public function parent() {
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

Then you will simply say:

```
$results = MyModel::with('children')->get();
```

Update for comment:

```
$results = Category::select('id','name')->with([
    'children' => function($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'parent_id'); 
        // You can customize the selected fields for a relationship like this.
        // But you should select the `key` of the relationship. 
        // In this case it's the `parent_id`.
    }
])->get();
```

Comment: And how to use it in controller?

Comment: Just act like you are using a normal relationship

Comment: thanks a lot . I select id , name from result with this code :$results = category::select('id','name')->with('children')->get(); .when I have child result have all column but I have only id and name column .

Comment: Updating answer for that ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98070/discussion-between-ozan-kurt-and-paranoid).